# Different value of C++ sizeof for the same class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory, new-operator

I used a static lib in my code in Visual Studio 2019. When I create a instance of the class from this lib in my code via new, it is 176 bytes long. When I delete the instance of the class, I got an error "CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer".

But all works Ok inside functions of the static lib: new and delete for the class works Ok, but class instance has 184 bytes length.

I copy all the defiles and other options from static lib project to my project but this doesn't help. 
My workaround is to create `CClass* create()` and `void remove(CClass*)` methods but I need to know where is the root of the issue.

Does anybody ever faced with such kind of issues?

Comment: Did you compile both the library and code using library with the same compiler?

Comment: You probably compiled your application and static library with different build options.

Comment: You probably mixte Debug with Release, or, the `lib` is generated with different CRT options

Comment: Do you use `#pragma pack` by any chance?

Comment: Hello, I used the same compiler Visual Studio 2019. Options are also the same: Multi-thread debug dll, unicode, debug.  I failed to find any #pgarma pack in the code :(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the static library was compiled with a different version of the class than the header included in the code which called it.

You could find out the source of the discrepancy and fix it.

However, the fix of `create` and `remove` static methods to handle constructing and destructing the object is actually a good idea.  For one, it encapsulates the allocation and deallocation to the static library which avoids discrepancies in the class definition used by the library verses the calling code.  But these factory methods can have other benefits too.  You might later find it handy to put additional code into the factory method.  Doing so may be handy for other encapsulation too.

Comment: As mentioned above, the source of the discrepancy can be compiler options such as pragma packing, debug options, and different compiler.  It can also be different class definitions, from different versions of the class prototype in the headers, or if the library did not use a header and just had the class in the source file.